# SQL Server 2016: Run xp_cmdshell as a different sysadmin user aside from the SQL Server service account

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, xp-cmdshell

I been trying to research this for hours and can't seem to find anything. Basically what I am trying to do is run a xp_cmdshell command as a currently signed in sysadmin user

To give some background, I have two accounts here

1. Domain\App_service
2. Domain\sql_service

Now SQL_Service and app_service are both in the sysadmin role. SQL_Service is what SQL Server is running as.

The problem I'm encountering is that when I run xp_cmdshell, it executes as the sql_service user. What I need to do is run this as the app_service as the command I am executing has the folder permissions locked down to app_service user

Here is an example of the code that I have tried to make it run as app_service

```
Execute as login='DOMAIN\app_service'
Exec xp_cmdshell 'whoami'
```

It keeps returning the sql_service user. From what I am researching, I believe that is intended by design. However, I am trying to run the cmd_shell as the domain\app_service user. This user is a local system admin and in the sysadmin server roles. And I'm running as this user in SQL Server Management Studio and the query is running as this user.

I keep seeing information around in regards to running non sysadmin users with xp_cmdshell. However, I'm not doing that. I'm simply just trying to run under a particular sysadmin user instead of xp_cmdshell running as the sql service username.

Comment: Xp_cmdshell does not allow OS user impersonation and it’s probably not a good idea to use it anyway. Better call a external service via MQ, HTTP or by having the external service poll a job table.

Comment: Anyone wrong with using the cmdexec step? You could then use a proxy.